# Silverstripe content block module error

Tags: php, silverstripe

I am using `Silverstripe 3.1` version and for a week I am trying to add a content block module to it. But every time I add module I get some errors. Now I am trying to add this one.

https://github.com/bummzack/page-blocks

Installation is clear, I edit the necessary files, add it to my `page.php` and when I make new page and try to add a text block to it I get error -

> `Error at line 761 of /...wwwroot/framework/core/Object.php`

Ok then I try to add other module , it is this - > https://github.com/NobrainerWeb/Silverstripe-Content-Blocks
When I add this module, the install is clean, no error in dev mod, db added perfectly. I see all block menus in admin panel, bet when I try to add blocks I get `internal server error`.

Can someone please help me?

I am despered. Sorry for bad English language, not my native.

Error;

```
[User Error] Uncaught Exception: Object->__call(): the method 'isnew' does not exist on 'TextBlock'
GET /admin/pages/edit/EditForm/field/Blocks/add-multi-class/TextBlock

Line 761 in /var/www/vhosts/erlanda/erlanda/wwwroot/framework/core/Object.php
```

Comment: okay, first things, check your PHP `error_log` and paste the full error stack trace

Comment: My error log file contain last errors from cahnges that i made in php files what i already fixed and deleted the changes that i made. Only error of my module problem is that what i put in my answer . Sorry i am big noob at all this

Comment: Is that isnew something that you added? Did you remember to run dev/build with flush ?

Comment: yes i did that, no i have not add it. Also most of modules do not work for me. Always get internal errors or this kind of errors. Dont know where the problem is.

Comment: I get this error __call(): the method 'isnew' does not exist on on other content block mods too. I need to fix some part of my code but i dont know where to look

Comment: If you are getting errors with most of the extensioms i have to ask that how are you installing them?

Comment: My first bet is that you are installing them just downloading the master and that probably does not work with 3.1. Also single extension might have  dependencies to another extension so to get All of them right you should use composer to install everything

Comment: Did you install the module using composer? And why do you use SS3.1? It's quite outdated now. For a new project you should use SS3.6 at the moment.

Comment: You probably just downloaded the module from GitHub... You need to install it using composer beause most of these modules have other dependencies which must be installed.